# when I add a file uploader in wicket form , the form disapear after submit

Tags: java, html, forms, file-upload, wicket

when I add a file uploader  in wicket form , the form disapear after submit, and a blank page apear instead . when i comment file uploader field every thing is ok . 
thanks for your help

in adduserPanel i call UserClassPanel :

```
    uploadfileForm = new Form("upoadfileWMC");
    uploadfileForm.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    uploadfileForm.setMultiPart(true);
    uploadfileForm.setMaxSize(Bytes.kilobytes(500));
    add(uploadfileForm);
    uploadfileForm.setMultiPart(true);
    add(uploadfileForm);
    fileUploadField = new FileUploadField("fileUpload");
    if (userClass.getdBId() == null) {
        fileUploadField.setRequired(true);
    }
    fileUploadField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    fileUploadField.setLabel(Model.of("بارگذاری کارت ملی"));
    fileUploadField.add(new BootstrapErrorAppender(fileUploadField));
    final FeedbackPanel fileUploadfdk = new FeedbackPanel("fileUploadfdk", new ComponentFeedbackMessageFilter(fileUploadField));
    fileUploadfdk.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    uploadfileForm.add(fileUploadfdk);
    uploadfileForm.add(fileUploadField);

    AjaxSubmitLink upload = new AjaxSubmitLink("upload", uploadfileForm) {

        @Override
        protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            target.add(uploadfileForm);
            target.add(feedback);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {

            final FileUpload uploadedFile = fileUploadField.getFileUpload();
            try {    
            if (uploadedFile != null) {
                    // write to a new file
                    File newFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/" + userClass.getMeliCode());
                    if (newFile.exists()) {
                        newFile.delete();
                    }
                    newFile.createNewFile();
                    uploadedFile.writeTo(newFile);
                    info("کارت ملی بارگذاری شد");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                logger.warn("can't write upload file :‌ " + ex);
                error("خطا در ذخیره سازی عکس");
            }
            target.add(uploadfileForm);
            target.add(feedback);
        }

    };
    uploadfileForm.add(upload);


    feedback = new FeedbackPanel("feedback", new ComponentFeedbackMessageFilter(upload));
    feedback.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    uploadfileForm.add(feedback);
```

in UserClassPanel.html :

```
<form wicket:id="upoadfileWMC" class="form-group">
     <!--<div wicket:id="upoadfileWMC" class="form-group">-->
     <label dir="rtl"  class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 control-label">بارگذاری کارت ملی</label>
     <div class="col-md-5">
         <input dir="rtl" wicket:id="fileUpload" type="file" class="form-control" id="choose-file" style="animation-fill-mode: both" required/>
         <button wicket:id="upload"  dir="rtl" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">بارگذاری فایل</button>
         <span  class="help-block with-errors" wicket:id="fileUploadfdk"></span>
     </div>
     <!--</div>-->
     <div wicket:id="feedback"></div>
</form>
```

and in addUserPanel.java i set an AjaxSubmitLink that submit all the other field in an upper form .

Comment: are there any errors in your server logs?

Comment: no any error, even when i debug project every thing is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I change my script so this event has occured .

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(""
            + "$(document).ready(function() { "
           // + "     $(\"#" + locations.getMarkupId() + "\").select2({"
           // + " language : \"fa\",dir:\"rtl\"});"
            + "     $(\"#" + roles.getMarkupId() + "\").select2({"
            + " language : \"fa\",dir:\"rtl\"});"
            + " });"));

}
```

I comment 2 line beacause i delete location choice and i thought there is no problem .  by the way it is ok now .